# Can you recommend Git principle to a new programmer?

Tags: git, github

Relatively new to Git. My work got a little messed up with the different commits, stashes, and branches. I know that Git can be used differently according to the task, but I would still love some good guiding principles. Here are some questions:

1. Read recommendations to commit often. On the other hand there are recommendations to commit only when your code is stable, which somehow contradicts.
2. Otherwise, read advice to stash often. However, stash does not include a message, and requires a different set of commands. Then you might return to a branch and forget about stashes which were done. Perhaps it's better to just stick to commits?
3. Would you recommend to Add and commit together in a one line command?

Comment: I almost never stash unless I'm going to pop the stash within a couple minutes. I agree, it's far too cumbersome to keep track of stashes in most cases (some tooling is better than others). I rely on commits instead and then I am comfortable doing "mixed resets" instead of stashes

Answer (score 2):

> Read recommendations to commit often. On the other hand there are
>   recommendations to commit only when your code is stable, which somehow
>   contradicts.

Yes, commit often. And learn how to split one commit fully or partially into several commits and how to squash several commits fully or partially into one.

> Otherwise, read advice to stash often. However, stash does not include
>   a message, and requires a different set of commands. Then you might
>   return to a branch and forget about stashes which were done. Perhaps
>   it's better to just stick to commits?

I personally don't recommend git-stash. Create temporary branches and commit the changes instead. Edit the commit message or run `git branch --edit-description <branchname>` to describe what the temporary commit or the branch is for.

> Would u recommend to Add and commit together in a one line command?

No. Always check the staged files carefully before commit. Make sure you have staged what you expect, no more no less. `git commit -am` could ruin your work if you are doing partially adding.

Update:

**How to squash commits into one and split one into several?**

```
git init test
cd test
> a
> b
git add .
#this is commit A and we are on the branch master
git commit -m 'root'
echo hello >> a
echo world >> a
echo nihao >> b
echo shijie >> b
git add a
#this is commit B
git commit -m 'english greetings'
git add b
#this is commit C
git commit -m 'chinese greetings'
```

So now we have three commits `A-B-C`. We think `B` and `C` are trivial commits and decide to squash them into one commit.

```
#move master from C to A and stage the changes of B and C
git reset A --soft
#make a new commit D that includes the changes of B and C
git commit -m 'english and chinese greetings'
#now master has moved from A to D
```

So now `master`'s history is `A-D`. `B` and `C` are still there but unreachable from `master`. We think `D` is too big and decide to split it into 4 small commits.

```
#--mixed can be omitted since it's the default
#move master from D to A but keep the changes of D in the working tree
git reset A --mixed
git add -p a
#Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
#input e to edit the hunk, and delete the line `+world`, save and quit
#now only the line `hello` is staged
#make the first small commit M
git commit -m 'hello'
git add a
#make the second small commit N
git commit -m 'world'
git add -p b
#Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
#input e to edit the hunk, and delete the line `+shijie`, save and quit
#now only the line `nihao` is staged
#make the third small commit O
git commit -m 'nihao'
git add b
#make the fourth commit P
git commit -m 'shijie'
```

Now the history is `A-M-N-O-P`. `master` moves from `D` to `P`. The chagnes of `D` is now splited into `M`, `N`, `O` and `P`. `D` is still there but not reachable from `master`.

Comment: "learn how to split one commit fully or partially into several commits and how to squash several commits fully or partially into one." Can you elaborate or refer me to understand better?

Answer (score 1):

Git has a very powerful branch and merge mechanism, use it

1. Always create a branch for any new feature.
2. On your new branch keep committing as frequent as possible. I usually do after a logical break point.
3. Once the code is stable and you think feature is complete, then you can merge the new branch into old branch.
4. If for any case you need to switch to other brach ( lets say for a immediate production fix), you can stash you changes and then switch branch. I use stashing when I am in middle of a change, but I want to switch branch for some reason.

As for add and commit together on single line is you personal preference. However, if you keep committing on logical break points, you would not need add and commit as frequently and just commit.

**Update**

Logical breakpoint can be anything, a new function or a feature, it depends what changes you are making. So lets say you are making changes, step by step. Whenever you think this step is final, commit. At some point you realize that you may want to go back a step and start over. Note just a step. Thats when you would go back to recent commit point. Now if you don't have a commit, it would be difficult to go back a step. So all the commits will show exactly how a feature was implemented.

I would suggest opening a new remote branch. As you push the intermediate changes it acts as a back up. otherwise changes are on your local machine only. If for any reason, the machine goes down, you have lost all your progress.

To begin with it might seem a lot of efforts. In my experience, we took about a week to get a hang of things, But now its become a part of our daily routine.

Do take a look at [git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#forking-workflow). for the first read, i would suggest observing how the code flows, rather than just commands. Once you understand it, and pick one that suites you best, you can then look at commands on how to achieve it.

Comment: Can u demonstrate what u mean by logical breakpoint with an example? A new feature, a new function, or something that will make sense when to other users or your future self? How often, or how much changes? 

As for branching - Do u also open a new branch on your remote github for each new local branch? Sounds like a lot of work. Or do u just have a remote master?

Comment: This is a good answer. I would add that sometimes in early stages of - say, a WordPress brochure website... you just want to get the thing up - and committing code is just *saving*. You may not need to take is as seriously -
 compared to a test-driven development sycle of a web-app. Once you have a usable site - **then** is the time where you want to really clearly organize your additions and clearly document what is being done.

Comment: Create a new branch to build out each new feature. Then merge that into your development branch and test on the staging server. If things are good - you can merge the branch to master or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

1.yes,commit often ,and it should not be contradicted to

> commit when your code is stable

The "stable" means you can pass all your test and you would want to roll back to this status if your fail in future step.When you commit often the step would be smaller which make you recall everything easier.So you should test your project often which is a good practice.That's a good principle bring out from << Test driven develop >> by Ken Back.

2.Since you commit often then stash often is not a problem.Stash when you commit.

3.That's personal habits not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've only started using Git too and have surfed quite a few folk's hubs too. A few things I had to learn the hard way were:

- Make sure your comments in commit relate to what you are adding
- Branches are your friends! Use them when collaborating
- Learning how to do pull requests is helpful too when working with multiple people